# R function to calculate values at different time point and plot a graph

Tags: r, loops, time, equation, curve

I am a beginner of R and would like to get some help from experts. 
I want to create a function to calculate risk under 3 conditions

1st: control: Xhh=0 Xmi=0

2st: hh:      Xhh=1 Xmi=0

3rd: hh+mi:   Xhh=1 Xmi=1

and compare between 2 groups

group 1: Xenv=50

group 2: Xenv=90

my parameters:

```
thi     lambda1 lambda2 lambda3 Beta Z2     Z1      Z4     Z3    Z6    Z5    theta
1.38    0.34    0.25    0.49    0.5  0.58   0.55    0.59   0.56  0.44  0.61  0.88
```

I want to plug in all these parameters into this equation
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYR81.png

and calculate the value at different time points,
Ti = from 1 to 10

For Ti=0, make the value at 0

and then plot a graph with the value at different time point, with 3 curves of these three conditions and compared between the two groups. So at the end having 6 curves in the graph.

Can anyone please offer some help?

Comment: You don't need a loop. Just write a function (i.e., you can copy the formula almost verbatim into R). The function will then accept time vectors as input. You might also be interested in the `curve` function.

Comment: Read this document: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a little more interpretation of your needs than you will tend to get here, but I was looking for a reason to procrastinate at other tasks this morning.

I think this meets your needs as stated:

```
#define a function called myfunction
myfunction <- function(lambda1 = 0.34
                       ,lambda2 = 0.25
                       ,lambda3 = 0.49
                       ,Beta = 0.5
                       ,Z2 = 0.58
                       ,Z1 = 0.55
                       ,Z4 = 0.59
                       ,Z3 = 0.56
                       ,Z6 = 0.44
                       ,Z5 = 0.61
                       ,theta = 0.88
                       ,Xenv
                       ,Xhi
                       ,Xmi
                       ,Tmin
                       ,Tmax){
  #this should make this function somewhat generalizable to values of T
  #create an empty vector to hold values of our function as defined
  f <- rep(NA, length(Tmin:Tmax))
  #loop through values of T in your function
  #check parentheses here - I make no promises
  #I'm also unclear what your value of thi is. I may be missing something, 
  #but I don't see it in the function you have written
  i <- Tmin:Tmax
  f <- -log(exp((-(lambda1*i)^theta)*exp(log10(1-Beta*Xhi)+log10((Xenv/100)*(Z2-Z1)+Z2))-
                  ((lambda2*i)^theta)*exp(log10(1-Beta*Xmi))*log10((Xenv/100)*(Z4-Z3)+Z4)-
                  ((lambda3*i)^theta)*exp(log10((Xenv/100)*(Z6-Z5)+Z6)))*(1-theta)+theta)     
  #set f=0 at T=0 (I think this is what you want)
  if(Tmin==0) f[1] <- 0
  return(f)
}


#you didn't specify how to plot, but this seems to lend itself to a ggplot facted viz.
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

#calculate for group 1
datg1 <- data.frame(t = 0:10
                    ,group = 1
                    ,condition1 = myfunction(Xenv=50, Xhi=0, Xmi=0, Tmin=0, Tmax=10)
                    ,condition2 = myfunction(Xenv=50, Xhi=1, Xmi=0, Tmin=0, Tmax=10)
                    ,condition3 = myfunction(Xenv=50, Xhi=1, Xmi=1, Tmin=0, Tmax=10)
)

#calculate for group 2
datg2 <- data.frame(t = 0:10
                    ,group = 2
                    ,condition1 = myfunction(Xenv=90, Xhi=0, Xmi=0, Tmin=0, Tmax=10)
                    ,condition2 = myfunction(Xenv=90, Xhi=1, Xmi=0, Tmin=0, Tmax=10)
                    ,condition3 = myfunction(Xenv=90, Xhi=1, Xmi=1, Tmin=0, Tmax=10)
)

#bind values together
dat <- rbind(datg1, datg2)

#melt your data into long format
datm <- melt(dat, id.vars = c("t", "group"))

#plot and facet
ggplot(datm, aes(x=t, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(.~group)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Roland. Got rid of the loop per your suggestion. Learned something new!